# drug "indicated in" malignant glyomas

Tags: prepositional-phrases

From a short description of a drug on a web-page:

> A chemotherapy drug (an alkylating agent) **indicated in malignant glyomas** and melanoma.

Is it acceptable to use this phrase? I found examples of "indicated in pregnancy" but I'm unsure whether this usage translates to "malignant glyomas", since it's not a human health condition but a kind of tumor.

Should it always be "indicated **in/for the treatment of** malignant glyomas", or is it acceptable to cut corners here for brevity's sake?

Comment: **Indicated** has become  medical shorthand for "suitable or recommended for the treatment of {malady}".  The preposition varies, "indicated with, indicated in, indicated for".   *The drug is indicated for hypothyroidism*. From 1900: https://books.google.com/books?id=OYlMAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA278&dq=%22drug+is+indicated+for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_39m--oLSAhWBRSYKHRSzA88Q6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22drug%20is%20indicated%20for%22&f=false shows the old meaning.

Comment: Here is the new "shorthand" meaning: https://books.google.com/books?id=utVOHYuhxioC&pg=PA403&dq=%22drug+is+indicated+for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx4fT3-oLSAhXK5iYKHV1PCnYQ6AEISTAI#v=onepage&q=%22drug%20is%20indicated%20for%22&f=false  *The drug is indicated for life-threatening ventricular arhythmias...*

Comment: @TRomano - yes, but **glyoma** is not a condition, like **arrhythmia**, but a tumor

Comment: Any malady or condition, broadly understood, which responds to treatment would be a valid complement, these days, for *{x} **is indicated for** {y}*, where {x} is the treatment and {y} is that which responds to treatment. The treatment can be a drug regimen or a surgical procedure. https://books.google.com/books?id=djcLBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA227&dq=%22is+indicated+for+tumors%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYtri4moPSAhXHYyYKHetcD-4Q6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22is%20indicated%20for%20tumors%22&f=false

Comment: @TRomano - so "Indicated in glyomas" is okay because glyomas respond to the treatment?

Comment: **in** is indeed one of the prepositions one encounters in medical literature with **indicated**.  I would say **for**.  **in** refers to the malady or condition as a *medical situation* or specific medical context, class of medical problem.  E.g. recreational drug use **in** teenagers.

Comment: In English, we take pills **for headaches** (i.e. to treat headaches).  But if you go to Germany and ask the druggist for some pills "fuer Kopfschmerzen" you're asking him for something to *produce* a headache.

Comment: The plural noun can be a proxy for the abstract class. "How do we treat *headaches*?"   "How do we treat headache?"  "How do we treat a headache?" The abstract class can itself be a proxy for situations involving its instance members, when perceived from the perspective of the medical practitioner. *Aspirin in headaches*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should use "*abc medicine* is indicated for treatment of *xyz disease/condition*." e.g. "...chemotherapy drug (an alkylating agent) *is* indicated in *treatment of* malignant glyomas and melanoma."

I would not sacrifice anything here for the sake of brevity, since this is disease treatment, and should be as specific as possible.  Therefore, I would NOT use the phrase as given.

In the PDR (Physician's Desk Reference) https://www.drugs.com/pdr/ and other drug references you will usually see lists both of indications, and of contraindications, for a given drug. Both imply *is* and *for the treatment of*.

note: This is very unlike the literal Russian use, where a medicine, for example, is *from* a disease or condition: oт гoлoвнoй бoли.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Yes, the phrasing is acceptable as written.

an *indication* in medical terms is defined as:

- *"a sign or circumstance that points to or shows the cause, treatment, or some other aspect of a disease."* (Miller-Keane)
- *"The basis for initiation of a treatment for a disease or of a diagnostic test; may be furnished by a knowledge of the cause (causal indication), by the symptoms present (symptomatic indication), or by the nature of the disease (specific indication)."* (Farlex)

Sources:
(Miller-Keane): indication. (n.d.) Miller-Keane Encyclopedia and Dictionary of Medicine, Nursing, and Allied Health, Seventh Edition. (2003).

(Farlex): indication. (n.d.) Farlex Partner Medical Dictionary. (2012).